# gradle copy include closure not working

Tags: gradle, include, copy

Gradle copySpec include closure not working:

```
def fileList = ["hello/world.xml"]

task foo(type: Copy) {
  from (zipTree("/path/a.zip")) {
     include { elem ->
         fileList.contains(elem.path)
     }
  }

}
```

The a.zip contains "hello/world.xml".

Message:

```
Skipping task 'foo' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
```

Answer (score 0):

A `copySpec` closure needs to be used with a copy task.
Your code is just the copy task, which requires a destination to copy into.

Your code should be more like this:

```
def fileList = ["hello/world.xml"]

def filesToCopy = copySpec {
    from (zipTree("/path/a.zip")) {
        include { elem ->
            fileList.contains(elem.path)
        }
    }
}

task foo(type: Copy) {
    into 'build/target/docs'

    with filesToCopy
}
```

See the API for more detail: https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html